# Linewidth and precision of ezplot

Tags: matlab

how is possible to determine "linewidth" and "precision" in ezplot?

from "precision", i mean that if in [1 2] interval ezplot is very pale in some locations or discontinues too, when using interval[1.5 2] to ezplot, discontinuity is removed and line is continues.

Comment: Could you post an image or some example code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little unclear what you mean by "precision". I think maybe you want to know either the number of plot points or the spacing between plot points. You can't *adjust* the number of points [EZPLOT](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/ezplot.html) displays (you would have to evaluate the function and plot it yourself to do that), but you *can* find out how many points there are and the spacing between them. Let's say you make this call to [EZPLOT](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/ezplot.html):

```
h = ezplot(fun,[minValue maxValue]);
```

This will plot `fun(x)` over the domain `minValue < x < maxValue`. If you don't specify a domain, [EZPLOT](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/ezplot.html) will use the default `[-2*pi 2*pi]`. [EZPLOT](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/ezplot.html) returns a handle(s) to the [line objects](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/line.html) that are plotted (`h` in the above code). You can access the [**XData property**](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/line_props.html#XData) of the first line object (if there is more than one line) by doing the following:

```
xData = get(h(1),'XData');
```

You can then find the number of points the line has:

```
nPoints = numel(xData);
```

and also the average spacing between points (what you may be referring to as "precision"):

```
delta = (max(xData)-min(xData))/(nPoints-1);
```

Also, you can change the [**LineWidth property**](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/line_props.html#LineWidth) of the lines with the following:

```
set(h,'LineWidth',2);  %# Sets the line width to 2
```

Answer (score -2):

If you add this to ezplot, specifying the domain as a vector it works.

```
ezplot(curve,[0:0.001:1])
```